# What modeling problem does ridge regression solve?

Tags: regression, regularization, ridge-regression, application

If your modeling problem is that you have too many features, a solution to this problem is LASSO regularization. By forcing some feature coefficients to be zero, you remove them, thus reducing the number of features that you are using in your model. LASSO solves the problem of too many features through feature selection.

What specific problems is ridge regression practically useful for solving? This question is looking for a canonical explanation of what problems ridge regression is used to solve today (in 2018).

Comment: Overfitting....

Comment: @RichardHardy Wikipedia says that it is 'more often' for underfitting. Google says multicollinearity in two of the top three hits. So which is it, and why?

Comment: @Sycorax I asked about specific applications of ridge, giving an example of a specific application of Lasso. The accepted answer to the other question suggests using Non-Negative Garotte. If only he knew that 8 years in the future L1 and L2 regularization would be easily implemented in any programming language that matters. In any case, that was a different question asked in a different world as far as computer implementations go.

Comment: That thread discusses the interpretations of LASSO and Ridge in a Bayesian framework (scroll down). https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151304/why-is-ridge-regression-called-ridge-why-is-it-needed-and-what-happens-when/151351#151351 This thread discusses how ridge regression provides for unique solutions to models which are not identifiable. Your comment mentions programming and software implementations - are these important aspects of your question? How?

Comment: No, ridge regression cannot help against underfitting. If that is really in Wikipedia, it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ridge regression is primarily a tool for dealing with colinearity. It does this by allowing some bias in exchange for greatly reducing the variance of the estimators. See e.g. [Ridge Regression](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Ridge_Regression.pdf), [ridge regression](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat857/node/155/), [Kim](http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~darrenho/SML/presentation%201.pdf), [Bager et al](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/81390/3/MPRA_paper_81357.pdf) and sources cited by those papers.

Comment: I'm always confused about the collinearity angle on ridge regression.  Most applications I see of ridge is controlling the bias-variance tradeoff, which has nothing much to do with co-linearity.

Comment: Why do you say it has nothing much to do with colinearity? One of the main problems with colinearity is that the estimators have huge variances.

Comment: The parameter estiamtes have huge variances, yes, but not the predictions themselves.  Ridge is very often applied in situations where the parameter estimates are not of primary (sometimes not of any) importance.  It's used to control the bias-variance tradeoff of the models generalization error.  I kinda think the collinearity thing is a red-herring.