# Why is Elastic Net called Elastic Net?

Tags: terminology, lasso, elastic-net, history, etymology

What is the etymology of "Elastic Net" in [Elastic Net Regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization)? Does it have anything to do with the name of "[lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics))"?

---

<sup>**Related:** [Why is ridge regression called "ridge", why is it needed, and what happens when $\lambda$ goes to infinity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151304/why-is-ridge-regression-called-ridge-why-is-it-needed-and-what-happens-when)</sup>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Zou and Hastie in their paper proposing the method give the following explanation:

> In this paper we propose a new regularization technique which we call the *elastic net.* Similar to the lasso, the elastic net simultaneously does automatic variable selection and continuous shrinkage, and it can select groups of correlated variables. It is like a stretchable fishing net that retains ‘all the big fish’. Simulation studies and real data examples show that the elastic net often outperforms the lasso in terms of prediction accuracy.
>
> - [*Regularization and variable selection via the
>   elastic net*](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/B67.2%20(2005)%20301-320%20Zou%20&%20Hastie.pdf) (2005)