# Using GLM with poly() function to look if there is an optimum

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, polynomial

I am looking for an optimum in weight for my research.

I used:

```r
glm(formula = PCRresult ~ poly(Weight, 2), family = "binomial", 
    data = dataset)
```

In the outcome it says:

```r
poly(Weight, 2)1  18.3227     5.1084   3.587 0.000335 

poly(Weight, 2)2  -6.8316     4.0989  -1.667 0.095578
```

At which of these two do I need to look if there is an optimum present in the data?

Comment: Make a plot! (and include it in the post)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28741/919 shows how to find extrema.  My post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/285148/919 discusses and illustrates some of the subtleties (including the possibility your optimum will occur at the endpoint of the domain of the explanatory variable(s)).  It doesn't matter that these posts focus on ordinary least squares regression, because `glm` uses monotonic link functions, meaning its optima can be found in exactly the same way using the same principles.